# How do i export with textures?

Tags: texturing, export

I'm trying to make a model for a mod and i'm not 100% sure how to export it with texture. I have searched all over the internet for tutorials but keep on failing. I know it probably me and you are annoyed that you keep on seeing this question.[image]

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=export+fbx+texture

Comment: answered here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures